# what would be the output of this program?

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    return n;
}
```

I know that if n is 0 then the program will be successful other times it'll fail. But I want to know if the program exits with some random return code like 1049, what would happen?  I checked this doc which mentions all possible exit codes https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exit-codes-in-c-c-with-examples/, but what if it doesn't match any of them?
Does it also depends on whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit system?

I want to know the detailed explanation of how the cpp code will behave?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice and there should also be a topic "why I shouldn't read geeksforgeeks"

Comment: Please note that the site you're linking to have a very bad reputation for "teaching" rather bad things. Bad habits, bad code and even *invalid* code. Case in point, a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or other good resource should have information about the return value of the [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) function. Also [never include that header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: haha, I don't usually read gfg. This was asked to me in an interview, for the codes only I checked the gfg because it was first link. :-))

Comment: Generally speaking, there's no fixed standard about the return value from `main`. C++ specifies `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` as `0` and `1` respectively, because that's the *convention* and commonly accepted behavior. Other programs can return other values to indicate other results. However, the POSIX standard (for Unix and Unix-like systems like Linux or macOS) specifies that the returned value must be in the range `0` to `255`. The other bits of the value are used for other things.

Comment: the return code is just a number, the way that's converted into the process exit code is OS specific, generally what happens as a result of the exit code is up to the calling process

Comment: got it, thanks all!

Comment: `// C++ program to demonstrate Segmentation Fault` is just another case of gfg spreading totally misleading information. Can this code produce a segfault? Yes. Does it always? No. The code has undefined behavior and for some reason they do not mention that at all. A site that uses code with UB and explains you what result to expect is bad. This example alone tells me that they do not actually understand what they are trying to teach. And there are many more.

Comment: `// C++ program to demonstrate TLE` -- That is another one to add to the misleading information by the gfg site.  That entire infinite loop could be optimized away by the compiler, because it doesn't have any side-effects.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that they make `TLE` appear to be a commonly used term, and that they make beginners believe such code should result in a  `Time Limit Exceeded` runtime error, and that they place that next to common interpretation of returns codes is hilarious

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and `// Below statement will give [...] and memory limit exceeded due to infinite loop` .... wtf